# I write simple wordpress loop for taxonomy.php file but don't show result

Tags: loop, taxonomy

I created a custom post type and create for CPT a taxonomy. but when I click on view taxonomy link don't work archive loop. I created taxonomy.php file for show this taxonomy in this file but display else result : "**Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.**"

```
  <?php
//this is register taxonomy code : 

  function airdrop_taxonomy(){
   $tax_labels2=array(
       'name'=>__('دسته بندی ایردراپ ها'),
       'singular_name'=>__('دسته ایردراپ'),
       'all_items'=>__('همه ی دسته ها ایردراپ'),
   );
   $args_airdrop_taxonomy=array(
       'hierarchical'=>true,
       'labels'=>$tax_labels2,
       'public'=>true,
       'query_var'=>true
   );
   register_taxonomy('airdrop_taxonomy' , 'myairdrop',$args_airdrop_taxonomy);
}
?>
```

```
//this is my loop in taxonomy.php file :
      
        <table class="table">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">عنوان</th>
                    <th scope="col">هدف</th>
                    <th scope="col">تاریخ شروع</th>
                    <th scope="col">تاریخ پایان</th>
                    <th scope="col">لینک </th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">1</th>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Otto</td>
                        <td>@mdo</td>
                        <td>@mdo</td>
                        <td>@mdo</td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

[image]

Comment: what is the show taxonomy link?

Comment: The function `airdrop_taxonomy` what did you hook it into? `init`?

Comment: @tomjNowell view taxonomy link .

Comment: @buttered_toast yes i used init hook : `add_action('init','airdrop_taxonomy');`

Comment: I don't understand, where is the view taxonomy link and how is it implemented? Are you using the `pre_get_posts` filter anywhere?

Comment: @tomjNowell  i uploaded image view taxonomy link in my question . no I don't use  `per_get_posts`

Comment: And is that your entire `taxonomy.php` file or just a part of it?

Comment: @tomjNowell No this is just part of ` taxonomy.php ` file . up this code is HTML code and `get_header` function. and under code is  HTML code `pagination` function and `get_footer` function

Comment: Try visiting Settings >> Permalinks in wp-admin to clear the cache & get the template file to be recognized

Comment: @admcfajn Thankyou . I do it but my problem don't resolved.

Comment: Is there maybe a taxonomy-airdrop_taxonomy.php file that has a custom loop which is causing the no post found message to appear falsely? When registering the post-type "myairdrop" do you have a 'taxonomies'=>['airdrop_taxonomy']? eg `register_post_type( 'myairdrop', [ 'taxonomies'=>['airdrop_taxonomy'], /* other post-type registration args... */ ])`